# Leveling a printer bed using the FEP in the tank?

Tags: bed-leveling

The gold standard for levelling the bed on a resin printer seems to be using a sheet of paper.

Is there any reason why is can't be done by lowering the bed to home while the FEP tank is in place and leveling it there?

I'm specifically thinking of the Elegoo Saturn, where the bed is levelled by undoing two bolts and moving it to home, and then tightening the bolts.

For situations where everything is covered with wet resin and you don't want to have to clean everything up or to risk getting resin on your glass. Not for everyday levelling.

Answer (score -1):

This method has a limited lifespan in solvent printers.

Its purpose is to achieve proper and optimal clearance to obtain suitable organs and structures.

It appears to be easier to adjust the FEP reservoir while it is fixed.

However, the issues present here can be more significant.

Any force that creates pressure on the FEP can result in punctures or leaks.

Printing with such qualities resembling this kind of problem can cause inferior prints.

I can recommend a clean cloth and a medium-soft brush as the simplest options for you. These will be sufficient for cleaning. If they are not enough for you, you can use some isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: Hi there, are you using ChatGPT (or some other AI) to generate these answers?

Comment: I am interested in 3D printers, there is a department in my company working on it. I received training on printers and I have certificates. I also love doing research.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying. I just had to check. I meant no disrespect, but community flags have been raised. Kindly retract the abuse flags that you have raised against my queries, as I am merely having to respond to and moderate community flags.

Comment: Here I answer questions and write questions. My reputation is being eroded by your account and votes. This lowers my motivation to write and answer questions.

Comment: With the greatest respect, I haven't downvoted *any* of your posts

Comment: Please don't get demotivated. I believe that some of the issues may have arisen from some posts where sources of the images, text and tables weren't explicitly provided, raising concerns of plagiarism. If any content (i.e. quoted text, image or table) is from an external source, then a reference or link must be provided. Also use block-quoting (`>`) on third party text, but only on third party text - there is no need to block quote your own text. If the content is your own then it is often wise to state that in the post (i.e. "This is a model that I made showing the effect"). Thanks.